# It is possible to rename defaults java packages without breaking Jhipster generator capabilities?

Tags: jhipster

I'm starting a new project with JHipster-6.0.1 and I would like to know whether is possible to rename defaults java packages without breaking *JHipster generator* capabilities. For example:

from `myapp.aop.logging` to `myapp.infrastructure.logging`

from `myapp.config` to `myapp.infrastructure.config`

from `myapp.security` to `myapp.infrastructure.security`

from `myapp.service` to `myapp.infrastructure.service`

from `myapp.domain`  to `myapp.infrastructure.jpa`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 4 changes are possible by changing `packageName` in `.yo-rc.json` or JDL file and then re-generating the app.

The 5th change from myapp.domain to myapp.infrastructure.jpa is not possible with the generator as it is, it can be done by [writing a blueprint](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/).